# onEdit trigger triggers notification email even when deleting value

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-sheets

I am running the following code in Google Sheets, in order to receive email notifications, if someone enters a certain value in a specific column. It works fine apart of the fact that it also triggers the email, if that certain value is being deleted. Is there any way to restrict the triggers to only send the notification when the value is being entered?

```
/**
 * add trigger for onedit - 
  * see menu -> Resouces -> Current project's triggers
 */
function Initialize() {

  var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();

  for(var i in triggers) {
    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
  }

  ScriptApp.newTrigger("sendNotification")
  .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet())
  .onEdit()
  .create();

};


/**
 * 
 */


function sendNotification(e) {


  if("E" == e.range.getA1Notation().charAt(0)) {

    if(e.value == "Value01"-"Value02"); {



  //Define Notification Details
      var recipients = "myemail@myemail.com";
      var subject = "Update " +e.range.getSheet().getName();
      var body = "New Update";

  //Send the Email
      MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you really have `"Value01"-"Value02"`  there? This is not a valid operation, subtracting strings. I can't reproduce the problem: in my script, the event object doesn't have the.`value` field when the edit is a deletion, so the comparison e.value == "string" cannot hold.

Comment: @zaq It's not like it matters since the statement following it is just a semicolon :)

Comment: @RobinGertenbach Ah, a typo question. Antal: don't put `;` after `if (condition)`  and it will work correctly (if the "string subtraction" is also fixed).

Comment: That's not the issue though. The comparison will return false and no email will send. if the onEdit event object has no value property Op can just check e.hasOwnProperty("value")